# how to change format date in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to change the format date and the value if null not display the default format 01-01-1970.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("allDepartment/onlySewingController/detailDprt2"); ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'Dinput': Dinput
            },
        }).done(function(dt) {
            if (dt != null) {
                console.log(dt)
                table.rows().remove().draw();
                $.each(dt, function(i, item) {
                    table.row.add([
                        item.date,
                        item.Attendance
                    ]).draw();
                })
            }
        })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82jQg.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are asking how to format your date in the ISO date format.

You should be able to grab the date and convert it to an iso date.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo site_url("allDepartment/onlySewingController/detailDprt2"); ?>',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    'Dinput': Dinput
  },
}).done(function(dt) {
  if (dt != null) {
    console.log(dt)
    table.rows().remove().draw();
    $.each(dt, function(i, item) {
      table.row.add([
        item.date.toISOString().split('T')[0],
        item.Attendance
      ]).draw();
    })
  }
})
```

A simple way to get the current date and format it as an ISO date, without the time.

```js
const date = new Date();
const isoDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
console.log('Current Date:', isoDate);

const specificDate = new Date('01-25-2021');
const specificIsoDate = specificDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
console.log('Specific Date:', specificIsoDate);
```

Comment: but the date data is obtained from my database

Comment: So it's a string- and not a Date Object? I have updated my answer with a way to render a specific date from a string.